# How can I install Selenium’s webdriver.exe in [PATH] htrough the project’s published installer?

Tags: c#, selenium, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have a Windows Forms application that uses Selenium. I have multiple production clients that need to run this application and I’ve noticed that in every new client (and also when I need to update the webdriver) I need to copy and paste the .exe to the [PATH] location (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps) and I want to automate that with the setup file that gets generated by Visual Studio every time I publish the application.

I’ve found that you can install an extension called “Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project”, include the .exe file on it and either make a new Form that’ll check if the webdriver is in place and if it’s not to copy it, or I can change the [PATH] of my IWebDriver object in order to reflect the new path of this file. As a bonus you can also add the the desktop icon.

But first I want to know if there’s a way to publish this webdriver.exe file to it’s proper address through the “Publish wizard” parameters before I start looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for my use case, for context, I'm using a windows forms project targeting .NET (framework) 4.7.1. these are snippets from my events "load" and "show" formated as a different function. I only included the logic behind the file check, download and unzip with overwite. Since the System.IO.Compression.ZipFile class for this version of .NET doesn't natively support overwrite files, I used Ionic's DotNetZip package downloaded from NuGet.

```
using Ionic.Zip;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

private void DriverCheck(){
    string edge, edgeVersion, edgeDriverPath, edgeDriver, edgeDriverVersion;
    edge = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
    edgeVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(edge).FileVersion;
    edgeDriverPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") + "\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\";
    edgeDriver = edgeDriverPath + "msedgedriver.exe";
    try
    {
        edgeDriverVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(edgeDriver).FileVersion;
    }
    catch
    {
        edgeDriverVersion = null;
    }
    if (!File.Exists(edgeDriver) || edgeVersion != edgeDriverVersion)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string winver;
                if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
                {
                    winver = "64";
                }
                else
                {
                    winver = "32";
                }
                string zipPath = edgeDriverPath + "edgedriver_win64.zip";
                client.DownloadFile("https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/" + edgeVersion + "/edgedriver_win" + winver + ".zip", zipPath);
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
                {
                    foreach (ZipEntry temp in zip)
                    {
                        temp.Extract(edgeDriverPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error downloading webdriver:\n" + ex.Message);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```